# issues with mixed tags

Tags: web-applications

how to have compatibility of html tags with other framework tags.

Comment: It would be curious if you specify what html5 tags you use and how it mixed with Struts2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at Struts2 [themes](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/struts-2-themes.html), the default ("xhtml") puts forms into a table. There is also one called "css_xhtml" which uses CSS for formatting. Another one called "simple" which just adds the elements, but field messages are not shown on simple.

In order to change the theme you need to specify the default in the struts.xml file by specifying:

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="css_xhtml" /> (for example)
```

You can also implement custom themes as they are simply a set of Freemarker templates. [This](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/working-with-struts-2-theme-template/) should help if you want to go down that route.